# iOS: log to file any crashing exception

Tags: ios, exception, nsexception

Any of you knows how can I log any crash exception from iOS app?.

I forcing a crash on my viewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSArray *myArray = [NSArray new];
    NSLog(@"%@", [myArray objectAtIndex:0]);
}
```

and I try to capture the crash in the console in my AppDelegate:

```
void uncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"CRASH: %@", exception);
    NSLog(@"Stack Trace: %@", [exception callStackSymbols]);
}

void SignalHandler(int sig) {
    NSLog(@"CRASH: %d",sig);
}
```

But this didn't work. Any of you knows how can register any crashing exception in iOS?

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually setting the exception handler using
`NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler`?

Something like:

`NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&uncaughtExceptionHandler);`

https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/1409609-nssetuncaughtexceptionhandler

Comment: I implemented NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&uncaughtExceptionHandler); and works. But how Can log the output to log ?